# Can an element overflow an element set to hide overflow?

Tags: css, html, overflow

Say I have a div with overflow-x:scroll and overflow-y:hidden.  Within that div there is another div that I would like to fully show.  It is fully viewable upon scrolling, as expected.

Is there a way to set an element to overflow it's parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, if the overflow on a parent element is set to hidden, nothing will overflow it visibly. That's what overflow:hidden is intended to prevent.

Comment: I expected that, but this is on overflow-y:scroll ... probably doesn't make a difference.  Just curious if there was a way to override it, like with !important.

Comment: @Spechal doesn't your code say `overflow-y:hidden`, not scroll?  !important overriding rules that are more specific in the cascade, but not rules applied to parent elements. Maybe inherited from, but not applied to, if you know what I mean. You'll have to change the parent element's settings.